# PrimeNG Slider - click event

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying out primeng's slider component and to my surprise I found out they do not have any `onClick` event for the slider, nevertheless I see they have `onChange` and `onSlideEnd` events exposed for the slider.

I want to perform an `http request` upon value change so I did this

```
<p-slider
       (onChange)="doHttp($event.value)"
       [(ngModel)]="sliderValue"
       [min]="0" [max]="100" [step]="1">
</p-slider>
```

which causes overhead when I slide the slider since multiple http requests are triggered, I tried to change it with

```
<p-slider
           (onSlideEnd)="doHttp($event.value)"
           [(ngModel)]="sliderValue"
           [min]="0" [max]="100" [step]="1">
</p-slider>
```

but now **http request is not fired upon slider click**

How could I achieve the behaviour I want? Should I add any kind of delay inside `onChange` event through a subject before emitting the http request? It seems very strange to me that they do not have an `onClick` event about the slider bar, so do I miss something here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rxjs [`debounceTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime) to reduce the number of calls made!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'slider-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: './slider-basic-demo.html',
})
export class SliderBasicDemo {
  private subscription = new Subscription();
  value!: number;
  private sliderSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.sliderSubject.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(() => {
        // do API call here!
        alert(this.value);
      })
    );
  }

  doHttp(value: any) {
    this.sliderSubject.next();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/c12gql?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fslider-basic-demo.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fslider-basic-demo.ts)

Comment: This approach is what I was thinking in the first place too but it is really surprising they do not already do that by exposing any input parameter for the delay or add an `onclick` event, I made slight changes to your example to make it functional so you can update your answer with [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/c12gql-nkqp95?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fslider-basic-demo.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fslider-basic-demo.ts) Thank you very much!

Comment: @NickAth As best practice we need to add the subscriptions, You're welcome!

Comment: Well in my project I pipe a custom operator that automatically destroys subscription upon the destroy of the component to avoid the boilerplate process of keeping all the subscriptions and unsubscribe to them upon component destroy, but indeed you are absolutely correct on this!

Comment: @NickAth Oh got it, then fine :)